# Question about the grid layout in my react app

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I was trying to display my images at a grid layout. But after applying the grid css feature, it was so weird that the grids were horizontally organized as the pictures showed. But I want it be well-organized, like 
two or three images each line.

My component hierarchy is ProductList -> Product -> Thumb -> images

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Filter from "./Filter/index";
import ShelfHeader from "./ShelfHeader/index";
import ProductList from "./ProductList/index";
import Sort from "./Sort/index";
import "./style.css"

class Shelf extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                < Filter />
                <div className="shelf">
                    < Sort />
                    < ShelfHeader />
                    < ProductList />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Shelf;
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from "./Product/index";
import Data from "../../../data/data.json";
import "./style.css"

const ProductList = () => {
    const renderedList = Data.goods.map(product => {
        return <Product product={product} key={product.name} />
    }
);   

    return <div className="image-list">{renderedList}</div>;
}

export default ProductList;
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
.image-list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px,1fr))
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Thumb from "../../../Thumb/index";

const Product = props => {
        return (
            <div className="shelf-item">
                <div className="shelf-stopper">Free shipping</div>
                <Thumb 
                    classes="shelf-item__thumb"
                    src={props.product}
                />
                <p className="shelf-item__title">product</p>
                <div className="shelf-item__price">
                    productInstallment  
                </div>
                <div className="shelf-item__buy-btn">Add to cart</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

export default Product;
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React from 'react';

const Thumb = (props) => {
    console.log(props.src.pictures)
    return (
        <div className={props.classes}>
            <img style={{width: "250px"}}
            src={`../../static/products/${props.src.pictures}`} 
            alt={props.src.name} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Thumb;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want there to be 3 of those product items in every row use:

```
.image-list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

This makes the grid split 3 equal columns for the product items. You can adjust how many splits each column has by adding or removing more fractions (`1fr`).

Remember the immediate children of the div with class "image-list" is what will be sorted into this grid and not the children elements within.

Comment: No problem, you can also adjust the number so that specific divs occupy larger space than others. E.g. `grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr` - the first div inside the grid will be as wide as the other two, and the other two will split its width evenly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `;` in the code.

```
.image-list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px,1fr));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, obviously adding a semicolon is fine, but I think it is not where the problem is.